# Cannot push JSON object into Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I know it seems like a duplicate but it isn't. Nothing worked, whatever I tried.

I have a list in my angular module:

```
this.checkedInterviews = []
```

and then a function that does:

```
var interviewModel = {
                        interviewId: self.pendingInterviews[i].id,
                        status: self.pendingInterviews[i].status,
                        location: self.pendingInterviews[i].location,
                        start: self.pendingInterviews[i].start,
                        hideCheck: null
                    };
 this.checkedInterviews.push(JSON.stringify(interviewModel));
```

I get `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`.
ANy idea what the problem is?

Comment: You've misspelled the Array when you've declared it. You're missing an I in intervIews.

Comment: because I handwritten that part right now but it's correct in the code

Comment: could you please give us more code? It seems like your function doesn't have access to this.checkedInterviews.

Comment: looks like `this` in `this.checkedInterviews.push` isn't the same `this` as the `this` when you `this.checkedInterviews = []` - as your code is extremely sparse, it's hard to say why

Comment: can you provide more code so we can check is the reference for `this.checkedInterviews = []` is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var checkedIntervews = []
var interviewModel = {};
checkedIntervews.push(JSON.stringify(interviewModel));
console.log(checkedIntervews);

(function arrayPush() {
this.checkedIntervews = [];
var interviewModel = {};
this.checkedIntervews.push(JSON.stringify(interviewModel));
console.log(this.checkedIntervews);
})();
```

You want to try:

```
var checkedIntervews = []
var interviewModel = {};
checkedInterviews.push(JSON.stringify(interviewModel));
$scope.checkedInterviews = checkedInterviews; //If using AngularJS because Angular is tagged in the question
```

**NOTE**: You should be able to use `this` if all of this is in the same function. This should work in the global scope as well. The only reason why I've used a IIFE is to separate out the scopes

Snippet added above with both cases.

If is not clear what `this` is in your question btw.

Comment: Wow ok I still get the error, it doesn't let me add an empty json either

Comment: Working snippet added

Comment: This doesn't reply to the question. You just created a new `checkedInterviews` (you mispelled: `checkedIntervews`) object `Array` and didn't answer about the `this` object. Why is `this.checkedInterviews` equal to `undefined`?

Comment: @TheProHands I've added a snippet with all of these things

Answer (score 1):

If they are putting in different functions then `this` in the second function is a different object.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, second function is using different `this`.

In Angular Module, you can assign `this` to some variable, then try to access it from second function.

E.g.:

```
var vm = this;
vm.checkedInterviews = [];
```

Now in function you should access it using:

`vm.checkedInterviews.push();`

Comment: This way could lead to memory leak. So you'd better handle carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
[Here is working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devidas7/Lvc0u55v/9586/)

```
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

  function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.checkedInterviews = [];
  $scope.pendingInterviews = [{'id':1,'status':'pending','location':'abc','start':'start'}];
  for(i= 0; i < $scope.pendingInterviews.length; i++){
      var interviewModel = {
                      interviewId: $scope.pendingInterviews[i].id,
                      status: $scope.pendingInterviews[i].status,
                      location: $scope.pendingInterviews[i].location,
                      start: $scope.pendingInterviews[i].start,
                      hideCheck: null
      };
      console.log(interviewModel);
      $scope.checkedInterviews.push(JSON.stringify(interviewModel));
    }
  console.log($scope.checkedInterviews);
}
```